# List manipulation algorithm is too slow

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

There is a sequence of n integers a1, a2,..., an. We need to change every element in the sequence with minimal element, which are placed before it. If there is no such an element, we need to replace it with -1. All changings are simultaneous and independent.

examples:

4 3 1 2 1 -> -1 4 3 3 2

5 4 3 2 1 -> -1 5 4 3 2

My code is too slow and doesnt passes tests with time-out errors when sequence is too big. How can I improve its performance?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nElements = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int tmp = -1;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (list.get(i) < list.get(j)) {
                if (list.get(j) < tmp || tmp == -1) {
                    tmp = list.get(j);
                }
            }
        }
        newList.add(tmp);
    }
    list = newList;
}
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that new value should be greater than the element we change.

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? I don't get the examples. Note that you can speed up `ArrayList` by giving a good estimate about the final size. You tell that in its constructor as `initialCapacity`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `4 3 1 2 1 -> -1 4 3 1 1` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need the inner loop. The minimal element before element i is the minimum of (minimal before element i-1) and (element i-1). You can do it in just one pass.

Comment: I forgot to mention that new value should be greater than the element we change. So 2 cant be changed to 1, only for 3.

Comment: In that case it's a much more tricky problem. You can do it in O(n lg n) time by maintaining a TreeSet of the earlier elements and using the ceiling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to cpp beginner's advice! Tree set and ceiling method made it work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nElements = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < nElements; i++) {
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Integer aList : list) {
        Integer tmp = set.ceiling(aList + 1);
        if (tmp == null) {
            newList.add(-1);
        } else {
            newList.add(tmp);
        }
        set.add(aList);
    }
    list = newList;
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is currently O(n^2) in time, where n is the size of the list, because of the way the nested loops are constructed.

You don't need the inner loop: you already have an upper bound on the next value to add into the list, namely the previous value in the new list. The next element will only be smaller if the corresponding preceding element in the input list is smaller. So just take the smaller of those two numbers.

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
if (list.size() > 0) { newList.add(-1); }
if (list.size() > 1) { newList.add(list.get(0)); }
for (int i = 2; i < list.size(); i++) {
  newList.add(Math.min(list.get(i-1), newList.get(i-1)));
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that new value should be greater than the element we change. So 2 cant be changed to 1, only for 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = {10,3,5,7,9,2,2,14,-5,7,9,3};

    if ( values.length == 0 ) { return; }

    int minValue = values[0];
    int temp;
    values[0] = -1;

    for(int i=1; i<values.length; i++) {
        temp = values[i];
        values[i] = minValue;
        if ( temp < minValue ) {
            minValue = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

You can just remember the minimal value until current item and replace it when you found a new one. This one is running in O(N) and doesn't require additional memory.

Comment: I think your code will keep writing -1 until a smaller value is found (also, note that the `int minValue` line fails if the preceding condition is false).

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner, I edited my original version which printed the numbers and didn't check it, my bad, should work now :)